# handling json response Array

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a json response as given below from backend
JSON:

```
{
    "json": {
        "response": {
          "servicetype": "1",
          "functiontype": "10011",
          "statuscode": "0",
          "statusmessage": "Success",
          "data":{
                "roleid": 36,
                "rolename": "Product Managers",
                "divisionlabel": "Department ",
                "subdivisionlabel": "Category",
                "roleinformation": {
                  "QA": [
                    {
                      "White Box Testing": 10
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "roleid": 38,
                "rolename": "Managers",
                "divisionlabel": "Department ",
                "subdivisionlabel": "Category",
                "roleinformation": {
                  "QA": [
                    {
                      "Black Box Testing": 10
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }

          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I have inserted my role names in a dropdown $scope.model.rolename .

If my rolename is selected as product managers I want to give value of my $scope.maxcount value as `"White Box Testing": 10` .It should be dynamic , based on selection the value will change. Now in dropdown if I select Manager the $scoope.maxcount for manager value will change. I have done till dropdown , dont know to handle after it .

JS:

```
` `UserService.getAssignRoles(json).then(function(response) {

 if (response.json.response.statuscode == 0 && response.json.response.statusmessage == 'Success')
{
    $scope.model.roles= [], assignrolesArray = [];

           assignrolesArray = unasresdata.concat(assresdata);

    $scope.model.assignroles = assignrolesArray;

}
});
```

HTML:

```
    <select class="form-control" name="role"
          ng-model="model.rolename"
          ng-change="getassignRole(model.rolename)">
    <option selected>Select Roles</option>
    <option ng-repeat="role in model.assignroles track by $index"
            value="{{role.rolename}}">{{role.rolename}}</option>
  </select>
  <input type = "text" ng-model=$scope.maxcount>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/keyurshah24/5kpxzrgf/

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your model.assignroles and scope value into this getassignRole() function and from that, you can get property and set it to your scope variable.

Do install [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) library and inject it.

HTML

`ng-change="getassignRole(model.assignroles, model)"`

JS

```
$scope.getassignRole= function(model.assignroles, rolename){
  console.log(model.assignroles);
  var test = _.filter(model.assignroles, function(o){
    return o.rolename === rolename;
  })
  console.log(rolename);
  console.log(test[0].roleinformation);      
};
```

Sample jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/alpeshprajapati/5kpxzrgf/1/

You can access required property then.

Hope it helps.